# Convert a shapefile with northing/easting to ASCII raster with latitude/longitude

Tags: arcgis-desktop, r, coordinate-system, saga

Linked below is a polygon shapefile whose projection is NAD83 and whose values are LU/LC codes. Coordinates are meters of northing and easting. I would like to convert it to an ASCII raster with coordinates measured in latitude and longitude. I'm sure it is a simple process, but I can't figure out the re-projection. Tools I have are ArcGIS or SAGA or R. I can even open the ASCII text and modify the header if no recalculation is necessary.

http://hawaii.gov/dbedt/gis/lulc.htm

EDIT: Thanks to Dan Patterson for pointing this out: the projection is actually UTM 4, and NAD83 is the DATUM. The output raster should have the same datum. If I want output to have lat/long coordinates, does that mean it has no projection?

Comment: Tricky. Is the shape file a regular grid of points in NAD83? Because even if you project those to lat-long you'll not get a regular grid out, so you then have to interpolate to a raster in lat-long. Its def doable in R with packages sp, rgdal, raster,etc...  Might get you a full answer later, no GIS capabilities on this phone...

Comment: The projection is Universal Trans Mercator, Zone 4 (Meters)
its datum is NAD83.  You have to define its coordinate system before reprojecting. In ArcGIS, use the Define Projection tool in arctoolbox, then project it

Comment: To carry on from the previous comment, you need to define the projection (as stated above), then project it to a Geographic Coordinate System (in ESRI-speak) which is result in decimal degree data, just ensure that you keep the datum the same.  These tools are all in the standard arctoolbox toolset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two tasks here. The first is to to coordinate transform (re-project) from UTM to Lat/Long (also called geographic or "no projection") and the second to convert from vector to raster.

In arcgis one approach is to use the [Project tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000007m000000.htm) to convert to geographic, then use one the **To Raster** geoprocessing tools located in the *Conversion Tools toolbox*, in this case [Polygon to Raster](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Polygon_to_Raster/001200000030000000/). And now finally [Raster to ASCII](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001200000005000000.htm) tool.

A second and perhaps more intutive vector to raster conversion is to load the shapefile into Arcmap, symbolize the polygons with "*categories > unique values*" as you want them to look, set the data frame coordinate system to Geographic NAD83 or WGS-1984, and then use *File > Export map*, save as TIFF with Format>"write geotiff tags" checked, bump the dpi and/or pixel dimensions up as you need them, then follow up with RasterToAscii.

Comment: Except, you'd want to reproject first, then rasterize second

Comment: eep! you're right, thanks for catching that. I've changed the order.